# HTTP push over 100,000 connections

Tags: http, comet, push

I want to use a client-server protocol to push data to clients which will always remain connected, 24/7.

HTTP is a good general-purpose client-server protocol. I don't think the semantics possibly could be very different for any other protocol, and many good HTTP servers exist.

The critical factor is the number of connections: the application will gradually scale up to a very large number of clients, say 100,000. They cannot be servers because they have dynamic IP addresses and may be behind firewalls. So, a socket link must be established and preserved, which leads us to HTTP push. Only rarely will data actually be pushed to a given client, so we want to minimize the connection overhead too.

The server should handle this by accepting the connection, inserting the remote IP and port into a table, and leaving it idle. We don't want 100,000 threads running, just so many table entries and file descriptors.

Is there any way to achieve this using an off-the-shelf HTTP server, without writing at the socket layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Push Framework : http://www.pushframework.com.
It was designed for that goal of managing a large number of long-lived asynchronous full-duplex connections.

Answer (score 2):

LightStreamer (http://www.lightstreamer.com/) is the tool that is made specifically for PUSH operations of HTTP.

It should solve this problem.

Comment: Looks nice, they have solved a much harder problem, but mine should be a subset.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at [Jetty + Continuations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations).

Comment: Very cool! Is this widely deployed? Are there any large installations?

Comment: Jetty is a widely used server, see jetty powered on this page - http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/. Jetty is now managed by the Eclipse foundation, so it has decent backing. That said, I *think* most people use versions of jetty without continuations.

Comment: Also, if Google App Engine is an option, you can look at their Channel API - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html